# is Tcp-Modbus basically a Cleint-Server socket communication?

Tags: tcp, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm building a TCP-Modbus application on PIC32MZ starter kit and My kit should act as Modbus-Slave device (read some data available on the ADC channels and send it to Modbus Master on every poll it will make), but I'm not sure, whether my device will be in TCP-Client (device will going to connect to a server) or TCP-Server (server will connect to my device) mode?

Regards,
Aatif Shaikh

Comment: Modbus TCP/IP: http://www.simplymodbus.ca/TCP.htm

Comment: TCP must establish a connection before transferring data, since it is a connection-based protocol. The Master (or Client in Modbus TCP) establishes a connection with the Slave (or Server). The Server waits for an incoming connection from the Client. Once a connection is established, the Server then responds to the queries from the Client until the client closes the connection.

Comment: If this is a standard way then it will make things more difficult for me, as the master has to keep the track of each slave's IP and port number (port number maybe not necessary if we keep all port number same). In my project, there are more than 400 slaves on the network. Hence, managing and keeping track of each device will be painful.